# Wildcard Text Index and inherited schemas

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have 1 root schema and 4 inherited schemas using a discriminatorKey
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html

In this scenario I'm not clear if I can use a wild card text index. The purpose is to index all the string fields of each inherited schema independently.
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/

**EDIT**
Adding this `myRootSchema.index({ "_type": 1, "$**": "text" });` on my mongoose root schema I get this error when I try to query. Should I repeat this on the inherited schemas too?

```
{
"name": "MongoError",
"message": "error processing query: ns=MYDB.caseNotesTree: TEXT : query=title, language=english, caseSensitive=0, diacriticSensitive=0, tag=NULL\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: failed to use text index to satisfy $text query (if text index is compound, are equality predicates given for all prefix fields?)",
"waitedMS": 0,
"ok": 0,
"errmsg": "error processing query: ns=MYDB.caseNotesTree: TEXT : query=title, language=english, caseSensitive=0, diacriticSensitive=0, tag=NULL\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: failed to use text index to satisfy $text query (if text index is compound, are equality predicates given for all prefix fields?)",
"code": 2
}
```

the query:

```
Model
    .find(
        { $text : { $search :req.query.q } }

    )
    .exec(function(err, data) {
        if(err)res.json(err)
        res.json(data)
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To efficiently utilize a [wildcard index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes) with inherited schemas, you'd want to use a [compound text index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#text-index-compound) using the `kind` discriminator field as the leading field in the index:

```js
{ kind: 1, "$**": "text" }
```

Comment: I haven't tested deeply yet, but it looks like it works!
I was sure I would get as first answer "mongoose doesn't allow that" :)

Comment: I've done some test now: I get an error, please refer to my edit

Comment: @the.websurfer Please create a new question rather than editing this one. The system isn't set up to handle non-trivial followups within the same question.

Comment: ok I made it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36056594/mongodb-error-failed-to-use-text-index-to-satisfy-text-query